# Simple question on random variables and statistics

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variables

Let X1 and X2 be 2 random variables. X1 = 20. X2 = 30. Each of those has a standard deviation of 5. 
If the random variables were normally distributed, what is the probability of getting such a discrepancy in random variables?

How can I solve that? Some hints or references to simple resources would be appreciated so that i dont need to read some 500-page volume on statistics.

Comment: What do you mean by "the probability of getting such a discrepancy"? The probability that $|X_1 - X_2| \geq 10$?

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to determine |X1-X2| == 10 probability? Actually it can be solved with Central Limit Theorem, but I dont know how either.

Comment: The probability of that should be $0$ - the probability of $X_2$ taking any particular value is $0$, so the probability of $X_2$ taking $X_1 + 10$ or $X_1 - 10$ is $0$.

Comment: Could you give some more detail on that? We already have the values of random variables. But if the value of X2 was not 30 but 25 for example, the probability of such an outcome is different (its just from my intuition) from the outcome that the difference between 2 variables is 10.

Comment: If you already have the value of a random variable then it isn't a random variable. What's the background to this question?

Comment: OK. Could you explain the normal way to find the probability that |X1−X2|≥10? The question is as it is. Its long version: "Worker a makes a measurement of detail: X1=20+-5 cm where 5 is standard deviation. The same detail is measured by worker 2. X2=30+-5 cm. What is the probability of getting such a discrepancy as they did if all results were normally ditributed?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be relevant. If random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent normal, with variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$, then $X_1-X_2$ has normal distribution, with mean $E(X_1)-E(X_2)$ and variance $\sigma^2=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2$. (Note that the random variables are not, respectively, identically $20$ and $30$: they vary, and from the estimated standard deviation, vary by quite a bit.)

In our case, we assume the means are the same, that is, that each measurement is *unbiased*. We also assume that $\sigma_i^2=25$. So the mean of $X_1-X_2$ is $0$, and $\sigma^2=50$. Unfortunately, neither assumption can be justified. But let's go on.

We want to know the probability that a normal with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{50}$ has absolute value greater than $10$. This is the probability that a standard normal has absolute value greater than $\frac{10}{\sqrt{50}}=\sqrt{2}$. A table of the standard normal gives that this probability is $0.157$. But one should not take the calculation  as giving any more than a ballpark estimate, since the standard deviation of $5$ is unlikely to be any more than an educated guess.